# Making post request using urllib

Tags: python, curl, request, urllib2

I am trying to make request on API provider

```
curl "https://api.infermedica.com/dev/parse" \
  -X "POST" \
  -H "App_Id: 4c177c" -H "App_Key: 6852599182ba85d70066986ca2b3" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"text": "i feel smoach pain but no couoghing today"}'
```

This curl request gives response.

But same request when I try to make in code

```
self.headers = { "App_Id": "4c177c", "App_Key": "6852599182ba85d70066986ca2b3", "Content-Type": "application/json", "User-Agent": "M$

self.url = "https://api.infermedica.com/dev/parse"

data = { "text": text }
json_data = json.dumps(data)
req = urllib2.Request(self.url, json_data.replace(r"\n", "").replace(r"\r", ""), self.headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

It gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "symptoms_infermedia_api.py", line 68, in <module>
    SymptomsInfermedia().getResponse(raw_input("Enter comment"))
  File "symptoms_infermedia_api.py", line 39, in getResponse
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Are you dead-set on using `urllib2`?  Because [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) has a much better interface for making http requests.

Comment: I flexible enough to try requests

Comment: @BrendanAbel: `r = requests.post("https://api.infermedica.com/dev/parse",json = { "App_Id": "7247c", "App_Key": "68599182ba85d70066986ca2b3", "Content-Type": "application/json"})` also gives same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the equivalent request using the python `requests` library.

```
url = "https://api.infermedica.com/dev/parse"
headers = {
    'App_Id': '4c177c',
    'App_Key': '6852599182ba85d70066986ca2b3',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
data = {'text': 'i feel stomach pain but no coughing today'}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
print r.status_code
print r.json()
```

But your real problem is that you're using the wrong header keys for their api.  It's `App-Id` and `App-key`, not `App_Id` and `App_key`.  It would look like this:

```
headers = {
    'App-Id': 'xx', 
    'App-key': 'xxxx', 
    'Accept': 'application/json', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Dev-Mode': 'true'}

data = {'text': 'i feel stomach pain but no coughing today'}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Also worth noting, they have a [python api](https://github.com/infermedica/python-api) that does all this for you.

Comment: @Brendam: Thanks for such sharp obeservation. I will take care this sort of problem in future

Answer (score 1):

`json_data = json.dumps(data)` is not the correct way to prepare POST data.

You should use `urllib.urlencode()` to do the job:

```
import urllib
data = { "text": text }
req = urllib2.Request(self.url, urllib.urlencode(data), self.headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

**[Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request)**:

> class urllib2.Request(url[, data][, headers][, origin_req_host][,
> unverifiable]) This class is an abstraction of a URL request.
>
> data may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server,
> or None if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the
> only ones that use data; the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a
> GET when the data parameter is provided. data should be a buffer in
> the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. **The
> urllib.urlencode() function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples
> and returns a string in this format.**

Comment: Have you double checked those parameters in `headers`? I guess there're some restrictions on server side.

Comment: If still it doesn't work, you could use a local proxy(e.g. fiddler) to debug this request, and find out the difference between curl and python request